# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) - C, Clion

Tags: c, struct, clion

I am running my InitializeMsgQs() function:

```
struct MsgQs_t *pst;

struct MsgQs_t queue[10];

void initializeMsgQs() {
    int qNumber = 0;
    printf("Enter queue number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &qNumber);
    *pst = queue[qNumber];
    printf("Enter identifier: \n");
    // assigning the identifier as an element in the queue array
    scanf("%d", &queue[qNumber].id);

}
```

Once i enter the queue number,i am prompted with:
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005), 
when i should be asked to enter queue identifier.

queue is a struct array of size 10, and id is of type int, inside the main struct.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `pst` and of `queue`.

Comment: You absolutely have to make sure that a) the conversion of `qNumber` actually _succeeds_ (return value of `scanf()` has to be 1, otherwise `qNumber` remains 0), and that the resulting number of `qNumber` is inside the bounds of the array `queue`.

Comment: Why do you need `pst` anyway? You don't use it anywhere. Show more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*pst = queue[qNumber];` should be `pst = &queue[qNumber];`. `queue` is an array of structures and `pst` is a pointer to such a structure. So you must place the address of the queueu structure in `pst`.

Writing `*pst = queue[qNumber];` is correct and would mean to assign the data of the queue element to what `pst` is pointing to. However, `pst` is not pointing anywhere (it is still 0).

See also the comment of Ctx about checking that a valid number was read.